# Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory error in JPA application

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc

I'm trying to create JPA app and i have problem while testing if it's connecting to MySQL database on MySQL server.

This is error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:78)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at com.javawebtutor.JPATest.main(JPATest.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
```

This is in my persistence.xml: I also tried with hibernate instead of javax.persistence.jdbc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ProjekatV2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.javawebtutor.Pacijent</class>
        <class>com.javawebtutor.Intervencija</class>
        <class>com.javawebtutor.BolnickaSoba</class>
        <class>com.javawebtutor.MedicinskiRadnik</class>
        <class>com.javawebtutor.Smena</class>
        <class>com.javawebtutor.Vozac</class>
        <class>com.javawebtutor.Vozilo</class>
        <class>com.javawebtutor.Zahtev</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:33060/infosys15495" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And this is my test class:

```
package com.javawebtutor;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class JPATest {

    private static EntityManager em;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ProjekatV2");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();

        createPacijent("Sladjana", "Nikolic", 1276948354);

        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }

    private static void createPacijent(String name, String surname, long brknji) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Pacijent pac = new Pacijent(name, surname, brknji);
        em.persist(pac);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

I GOT SOLUTION: 
I had to change persistence.xml header to:

```
<persistence version="2.0"   
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
```

-Thanks Joseph!

Comment: with the exception thrown . it look like you need to add some dependency library to hibernate . because the class org.dom4j.DocumentException could not be found. i think you should try install dom4j to your classpath

Comment: @JosephPeter I posted a new error after i add dom4j...

Comment: @JosephPeter Thank you bro you helped me find d wei :D

Comment: you are welcome! Let me post the comment as an answer! So that it migth be usefull for others too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the exception thrown . it look like you need to add some dependency library to hibernate . because the class org.dom4j.DocumentException could not be found. i think you should try install dom4j to your classpath